# Regex replacement one a single line with a repetitive pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have the following **single line** of code:

```
<script src="common/scripts/vendor.0.js"></script><script src="common/scripts/all.0.js"></script><script src="common/scripts/environment.0.js"></script><script src="vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script><script src="common/scripts/another.0.js">
```

I basically want to **match and replace** the following string:

```
<script src="vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

The key pattern to match is that it's a `<script>` tag pointing to the `angular-mocks.js` file, the path could be changed in the future. But the replacement must be for the whole `<script>` tag.

Also, the `0` in all the files will actually contain the build number from Jenkins, in case it's relevant for you to know.

Can anyone help me with a regex to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script[^>]+?angular-mocks\.js"><\/script>
```

Very similar to Qeole's answer, but implementation agnostic; you may need additional escaping.  If you're using JS, PCRE or PY, here's a link to [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lS5aB2).

***Edit***

If `src` isn't guaranteed to be the last attribute within the tag, use:

```
<script[^>]+?angular-mocks\.js"[^>]*><\/script>
```

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nO2pY6)

Answer (score 0):

With a `sed` command, you could use:

```
sed 's=<script [^>]*angular-mocks.js"></script>=='
    <<< '<script src="common/scripts/vendor.0.js"></script><script src="common/scripts/all.0.js"></script><script src="common/scripts/environment.0.js"></script><script src="vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script><script src="common/scripts/another.0.js">'
```

(Match `<script`, then a string without any `>`, then `angular-mocks.js></script>` and delete the whole thing.)